# Difference number of Commands in CMD (Windows OS vs RE)

Tags: cmd.exe

A couple of days ago I noticed that  in Windows Recovery Environment (at boot) there are some commands (bootrec for example)  which are recognized when type in the CMD (Command Prompt) but are not recognized as a command when you input it in Windows CMD. There are some commands that recognizable on both environments in CMD like (diskpart for example)

Is there a list which shows which command is recognizable in both environments, which is recognizable in RE but not in Windows OS,  and which is vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

[WinRE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn898523.aspx) is [WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive) with one, or both, of two specific WinRE [Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference#winpe-optional-components) (packages) [installed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-mount-and-customize) into the image:

- [WinPE-Rejuv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference#21)
- [WinPE-SRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference#22)

WinPE contains certain binaries within it's WIM image to facilitate Deployment & Imaging of WIM/ESD images, as well as specific binaries for repairing a current Windows install.

- `bootrec` is the only one the vast majority of users will ever interact with.

  - Several WinRE specific binaries are for customizing the image itself for front end use by a user *(such as adding custom options to the Advanced Options blue screen boot page)*

WinPE and Windows share many of the same basic binaries found in `%WinDir%` and `%WinDir%\System32`, which is why many of the same commands are recognizable in both, however as to a diff list, that I'm not sure of.

Comment: I'm not very big in Windows system. What I wanted to know was which commands are functional in Windows Recovery Command Prompt? and which commands are functional in Windows OS Command Prompt (CMD.exe) ? So  from both list you could see the differences.

Comment: @Tomsofty33 I don't believe there's a diff list of specific commands, or at least I've never come across one, however what might be a better question is what binaries are present in WinPE/RE that are not present in a live Windows install.  To determine this, you'd perform a recursive search, directing output to separate text files, for executable binaries  _(`*.com` | `*.dll` | `*.exe`)_ within `%WinDir%` in both WinPE/RE and a live Windows install, then perform a diff view on those two text files.

Comment: So you mean there is no  listing of commands that is recognizable in the CMD of the recovery environment?

Comment: @Tomsofty33 Not that I'm aware of, as 99% of binaries in WinPE are present in Windows.  While `cmd /c help` will output a list of commands [most are actual binaries], it's not exhaustive, nor does it list the majority of commands available.  If you require a list, my previous suggestion would be a fairly easy way to garnish a list (I'd perform a `.dll` search separate from a `.com`/`.exe` search, as most DLLs aren't cmd accessible binaries [some are].  The main difference I'm aware of is `bootrec.exe`, as it can't be used when booted to Windows.